# Rails - why my posts form works different from comments form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

posts_controller.rb:

```
 def create
    @post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
    if @post.save
      flash[:success] = "Post created!"
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'pages/home'
    end
      end

   private

    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:content)
    end
```

post form:

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Compose new post..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

comments_controller.rb:

```
def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:comment][:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Comment created!"
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
            flash[:danger] = "Comment failed, try again."
            redirect_to post_path(@post)
        end
      end

  private

    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
    end
```

comments form:

```
<%= form_for(@comment) do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Comment..." %>
  </div>
  <%= f.hidden_field :post_id , value: @post.id %>   // WHY DO I NEED THIS?
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id , value: current_user.id %>  // AND THIS?
  <%= f.submit "Post", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Why do I need them hidden fields to make it work with comments while they aren't needed for posts? My code is working, I was able to google a solution but still interested why exactly comments work different from posts. Sorry for a silly question, but as a beginner I'm looking for analogies :)

Answer (score 0):

basic idea here is when you submit that comment from, it will post both of these ids along with other params to your comments create action. So that you can use these ids to find model objects.

But in your case, u don't need user id as it's already available in current_user helper.

Comment: somehow it doesnt work without hidden fields... and I wonder why

Comment: As you already have post associated with comment I don't think u need it either, can you post the error u received

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /comments
Couldn't find Post without an ID

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need current_user.id. Current user is consistent through view and controller, and it may cause a security threat to put it in the form. (a playful user can post a comment on behalf of another user)

Secondly,  You needed to add post_id as a hidden filed for comment because the post_params is basically title/body, etc, all user submitted values. However, comment need a application defined value, which is post_id.Take a look at https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/wiki/A-guide-to-doing-nested-model-forms for using nested forms that helps with your one-to-many associations.

What you need is to create comments through an update action in posts_controller. So that you can keep the same pattern and your code stays clean.

This tutorial should be helpful for you:
http://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/

Comment: added:

`class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many   :comments, dependent: :destroy
  ** accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true **
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates  :user_id, presence: true
  validates  :content, presence: true
end`


ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /comments
Couldn't find Post without an ID

Comment: Did you make the changes to your form / controller?

Comment: nope, it just doesnt work without the id sent via hidden field

Comment: take a look that this controller and view: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon_simple_form_demo/blob/master/app/controllers/projects_controller.rb. You need to follow the same pattern.

Comment: https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon_simple_form_demo/blob/master/app/views/projects/_form.html.slim. Also see my updated answer.

Comment: so I need to have the ids in params.require(:project).permit? is it safer this way?

Comment: i wouldn't say it is necessarily safer (depends on what you mean, can you elaborate?) , but for sure this ensures you that your controller follows the same pattern and your code stays organized and clean :)